# Kafka Client compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

we are using the following Kafka client on our Linux red-hat servers

```
0.8.1 Release
Released March 12, 2014
Release Notes
Source download: kafka-0.8.1-src.tgz (asc, md5)
Binary downloads:
Scala 2.8.0 - kafka_2.8.0-0.8.1.tgz (asc, md5)
Scala 2.8.2 - kafka_2.8.2-0.8.1.tgz (asc, md5)
Scala 2.9.1 - kafka_2.9.1-0.8.1.tgz (asc, md5)
Scala 2.9.2 - kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.tgz (asc, md5)
Scala 2.10 - kafka_2.10-0.8.1.tgz (asc, md5)
We build for multiple versions of Scala. This only matters if you are using Scala and you want a version built for the same Scala version you use. Otherwise any version should work (2.9.2 is recommended).
```

from Kafka broker side , we upgrade the Kafka brokers versions to 1.X version

now we need to know if Kafka Client compatibility ( 0.8.1 ) is fit the  Kafka broker - 1.0

after searching we found this post [Determine the Kafka-Client compatibility with kafka-broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691662/determine-the-kafka-client-compatibility-with-kafka-broker)

but we not found the Kafka client 0.8.1 compatibility with Kafka broker versions

how to know what is the Kafka brokers version that fit Kafka client version - 0.8.1 ?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and running Kafka 1.0 on your own computer, then taking your producer and consumer code, and just testing it out??

Comment: still not , I guess it will be work , but we want to work according to the right rules

Comment: Some experimentation would be easier than scanning wiki pages, in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka clients running 0.8.1 are **not** compatible with 1.0 brokers, or even 0.9 brokers due to KIP-35 which includes protocol versions within the client API requests to handle better cross-version support

You can refer to the wiki here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

I would suggest going to a 2.x release as well

Comment: do you means that we need to install the client 2.X  ?

Comment: we are using HDP 2.6.5

Comment: from the link -  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix  , how you identify the right kafka version fro client 0.8.1?

Comment: I suggest you gather a list of all breaking changes, starting with 0.9, then going upwards until you're comfortable. I'd also suggest upgrading to 0.9, then 0.10, then 0.11, as the APIs changed enough in those versions. From there, it can be safer to go straight to 2.x, in my opinion... https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#upgrade

Comment: Click the first link. KIP-35 was not added until 0.10.2

Comment: Alternatively, assuming that you need no old data, just get some more hardware and install a brand new cluster.

Comment: yes I click on the link - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-35+-+Retrieving+protocol+version , but not found the info about client 0.8.1 to kafka 1.X

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205505/discussion-between-jessica-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Does it need to say it? The compatibility link says "any KIP-35 enabled client". If you refer to that KIP, it was not available until much after 0.8, therefore it is not compatible

Comment: how we get list of all kafka client versions that fit the kafka 1.X from HDP 2.6.5 )

Comment: Just use the ones from maven central. Kafka is still kafka. 0.10.2 and higher will work, as shown in the wiki

Comment: what you means "Kafka is still kafka. 0.10.2" , we have kafka version 1.X

Comment: There is a period there. Kafka is still kafka... HDP provided or not should make no difference. Spark, Nifi, external clients will continue to work should you chose to maintain Kafka with its own tools outside of HDP

Comment: another question  -  we have also old Kafka version -  0.10 version ( from HDP 2.6.4 )  , what are the range of Kafka clients versions that supported the Kafka broker - 0.10?