# Kafka aborting producer batches due to fatal error

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

I use Spring kafka for my application. It's working perfectly with spring boot version 2.3.2, but when I upgrade to 2.7.0, below error:

```
2022-05-27 15:32:33.357 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [main,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.KafkaProducer.configureTransactionState:532 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2022-05-27 15:32:33.392 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [main,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.s.a.AbstractLogin.login:61 - Successfully logged in.
2022-05-27 15:32:33.430 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [main,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.utils.AppInfoParser.<init>:119 - Kafka version: 3.0.1
2022-05-27 15:32:33.432 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [main,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.utils.AppInfoParser.<init>:120 - Kafka commitId: 8e30984f43e64d8b
2022-05-27 15:32:33.432 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [main,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.utils.AppInfoParser.<init>:121 - Kafka startTimeMs: 1653640353428
2022-05-27 15:32:34.350 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,,] INFO  o.a.kafka.clients.Metadata.update:287 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: XeVfqn0-QOOFk9uCnDkisw
2022-05-27 15:32:34.354 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,,] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.i.TransactionManager.transitionToFatalError:500 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
2022-05-27 15:32:34.386 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,,] ERROR o.a.k.c.p.internals.Sender.maybeAbortBatches:497 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
2022-05-27 15:32:34.387 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,,] ERROR o.a.k.c.p.internals.Sender.maybeAbortBatches:497 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
2022-05-27 15:32:34.388 "ubuntu1804" "core-service" [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1,,] ERROR o.a.k.c.p.internals.Sender.maybeAbortBatches:497 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Aborting producer batches due to fatal error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.
```

Here is my kafka configuration:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: 10.98.0.1:9092,10.98.0.2:9092,10.98.0.3:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      properties:
        security:
          protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
        sasl:
          mechanism: PLAIN
          jaas:
            config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=${KAFKA_USERNAME:myuser} password=${ENV_KAFKA_PASSWORD:mypassword};
```

Here is my logging config

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        web: INFO
      apache:
        kafka: INFO
```

When I set logging level to OFF, there is no error anymore. But I just want to know why and how to fix it. Thank you in advance

Comment: It's strange. It's authentication related. Since you turned off the logs, you are not seeing this error. Does your application work?

Comment: no it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be due to the version of the kafka client, which is not compatible with the kafka broker servion. Change the version of kafka client accordingly.

**Other sources**
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691662/determine-the-kafka-client-compatibility-with-kafka-broker)

Comment: Upvoted ! . Thanks , this helped me to fix something I have been finding for a long time